# Creating jTable in java with multiple number of rows in a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello all I am creating a table to display some thing like this. Is it possible to create a formatted jTable like this. If yes help me to do it in a better way. None of the links in Google helped me to do so.

[image: Model of table to be created in java]

Comment: Stole [link from MadProgrammer](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples4.html) :-D -> Voting to close as too broad

Comment: I am selecting the value from database. If so how can I create this table. In first row there are 3 and in second there are 4 and in 3rd there are 1 like wise it may change. Is there any easy way to do this?